# How to return the most common files extensions form a list of filenames?

Tags: python, statistics, counting

I was given lists, that contains filenames with extensions, and asked to write a function to count the most common extension in every list, and return the results.

Example:

```py
["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar", "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3", "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe", "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html", "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", 
...
"delirious.cpp"]) == [".cpp", ".html"]
```

The result of this example must be `.cpp` and `.html`, as the most common extensions.

I tried using `split()`, to get rid of files names, and keep only the extensions, and then I can count them using `count()` and `most_common()`, but the result was after splitting, I got the letters counted, not the extensions.

The result of splitting:

```
pr
html
wav
mp3
jar
cpp
xml
js
jar
mp3
...
```

and the result of counter(), and most_common() was:

```
[('p', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

the function that I wrote:

```
import traceback
from collections import Counter

def extension(files):
files_list = [files]    
for file in files_list:
    for name in file:
        split_it = name.split(".")[-1]
        print(split_it)
        
    counter = Counter(split_it)
    most_occur = counter.most_common()
    return most_occur
    
    extension(["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar",
                  "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3",
                  "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "icky.wav",
                  "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe",
                  "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "annoyed.xml",
                  "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "complex.exe",
                  "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html",
                  "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "hanging.css",
                  "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "fortunate.wp",
                  "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", "exclusive.als",
                  "glossy.css", "fluffy.pt", "cluttered.txt", "halting.cpp", "glib.cpp", "aback.pr",
                  "cynical.Ue4", "chilly.xml", "hideous.ala", "finicky.txt", "feigned.ala", "better.Ue4",
                  "dear.py", "available.xml", "easy.pr", "fine.mp3", "cowardly.jar", "incredible.css",
                  "adhesive.exe", "energetic.mp3", "harmonious.exe", "general.als", "condemned.als",
                  "flawless.als", "curvy.h", "ambitious.mp3", "disillusioned.xml", "bitter.h",
                  "hanging.wp", "certain.cpp", "flashy.html", "cuddly.pr", "cagey.Ue4", "extra-small.pr",
                  "amuck.cpp", "direful.html", "delightful.als", "helpless.h", "foamy.mp3", "enthusiastic.maya",
                  "good.maya", "adhesive.css", "imperfect.pr", "bent.cpp", "exultant.zbrush", "adorable.mp3",
                  "clammy.maya", "gaudy.pt", "blushing.css", "cuddly.Ue4", "curved.py", "boring.html", "broken.txt",
                  "daily.jar", "giddy.xml", "curved.css", "future.maya", "graceful.css", "guiltless.maya",
                  "gentle.cpp", "few.css", "calculating.txt", "clear.pr", "grey.py", "entertaining.ala",
                  "elfin.txt", "excited.js", "abject.zbrush", "best.js", "boundless.wav", "hurried.ala",
                  "delirious.cpp"]) == [".cpp", ".html"]
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am new to python, and still trying to figure even the simplest things out.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, i used bits of every code you wrote to fit my program requirements, Thanks to you, Have a good day.

Comment: I thought I commented here, but it seems like my comment was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, consider using [statistics.multimode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) (requires Python >= 3.8):

```
>>> from statistics import multimode
>>> multimode(f.split('.')[-1] for f in files)
['html', 'cpp']
```

This will automatically select all of the most common extensions if there's a tie.

If the list can contain files with no extension, use this instead:

```
>>> multimode(x[-1] for f in files if (x := f.split('.')))
['html', 'cpp']
```

or perhaps:

```
>>> multimode(f.split('.')[-1] for f in files if '.' in f)
['html', 'cpp']
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is, that `split_it` is not a `list` in your case it is the last result from iterating your `files_list` -> `ccp`

So `Counter('cpp').most_common()` will only count the characters of your single `string`.

Instead give `Counter()` a `list` of your splitted extensions:

```
Counter([file.split('.')[-1] for file in files]).most_common()
```

---

Another issue is, you could not simply call `most_common(n)` - There can several items exists with same count, as in your case `('html', 10), ('cpp', 10)`

So you have to itereate the `most_common()` comparing the first item with the following items by its count:

```
most_common = Counter([file.split('.')[-1] for file in files]).most_common()
['.'+c[0] for c in most_common if c[-1] == most_common[0][-1]]
```

###### Example

```
from collections import Counter

def top_extensions (files):

    most_common = Counter([file.split('.')[-1] for file in files]).most_common()

    return ['.'+c[0] for c in most_common if c[-1] == most_common[0][-1]]    

files = ["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar",
                  "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3",
                  "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "icky.wav",
                  "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe",
                  "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "annoyed.xml",
                  "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "complex.exe",
                  "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html",
                  "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "hanging.css",
                  "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "fortunate.wp",
                  "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", "exclusive.als",
                  "glossy.css", "fluffy.pt", "cluttered.txt", "halting.cpp", "glib.cpp", "aback.pr",
                  "cynical.Ue4", "chilly.xml", "hideous.ala", "finicky.txt", "feigned.ala", "better.Ue4",
                  "dear.py", "available.xml", "easy.pr", "fine.mp3", "cowardly.jar", "incredible.css",
                  "adhesive.exe", "energetic.mp3", "harmonious.exe", "general.als", "condemned.als",
                  "flawless.als", "curvy.h", "ambitious.mp3", "disillusioned.xml", "bitter.h",
                  "hanging.wp", "certain.cpp", "flashy.html", "cuddly.pr", "cagey.Ue4", "extra-small.pr",
                  "amuck.cpp", "direful.html", "delightful.als", "helpless.h", "foamy.mp3", "enthusiastic.maya",
                  "good.maya", "adhesive.css", "imperfect.pr", "bent.cpp", "exultant.zbrush", "adorable.mp3",
                  "clammy.maya", "gaudy.pt", "blushing.css", "cuddly.Ue4", "curved.py", "boring.html", "broken.txt",
                  "daily.jar", "giddy.xml", "curved.css", "future.maya", "graceful.css", "guiltless.maya",
                  "gentle.cpp", "few.css", "calculating.txt", "clear.pr", "grey.py", "entertaining.ala",
                  "elfin.txt", "excited.js", "abject.zbrush", "best.js", "boundless.wav", "hurried.ala",
                  "delirious.cpp"]

top_extensions (files)
```

Answer (score 0):

below should work

```
import traceback
from collections import Counter

def extension(files):
    files_list = [files]    
    kkk = []
    for file in files_list:
        for name in file:
            split_it = name.split(".")[-1]
            print(split_it)
            kkk.append(split_it)
    counter = Counter(kkk)
    mostoccur = counter.most_common(2)
    mostoccur = ["." + i[0] for i in mostoccur]
    mostoccur.sort()
    return mostoccur

inputs = ["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar",
                  "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3",
                  "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "icky.wav",
                  "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe",
                  "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "annoyed.xml",
                  "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "complex.exe",
                  "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html",
                  "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "hanging.css",
                  "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "fortunate.wp",
                  "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", "exclusive.als",
                  "glossy.css", "fluffy.pt", "cluttered.txt", "halting.cpp", "glib.cpp", "aback.pr",
                  "cynical.Ue4", "chilly.xml", "hideous.ala", "finicky.txt", "feigned.ala", "better.Ue4",
                  "dear.py", "available.xml", "easy.pr", "fine.mp3", "cowardly.jar", "incredible.css",
                  "adhesive.exe", "energetic.mp3", "harmonious.exe", "general.als", "condemned.als",
                  "flawless.als", "curvy.h", "ambitious.mp3", "disillusioned.xml", "bitter.h",
                  "hanging.wp", "certain.cpp", "flashy.html", "cuddly.pr", "cagey.Ue4", "extra-small.pr",
                  "amuck.cpp", "direful.html", "delightful.als", "helpless.h", "foamy.mp3", "enthusiastic.maya",
                  "good.maya", "adhesive.css", "imperfect.pr", "bent.cpp", "exultant.zbrush", "adorable.mp3",
                  "clammy.maya", "gaudy.pt", "blushing.css", "cuddly.Ue4", "curved.py", "boring.html", "broken.txt",
                  "daily.jar", "giddy.xml", "curved.css", "future.maya", "graceful.css", "guiltless.maya",
                  "gentle.cpp", "few.css", "calculating.txt", "clear.pr", "grey.py", "entertaining.ala",
                  "elfin.txt", "excited.js", "abject.zbrush", "best.js", "boundless.wav", "hurried.ala",
                  "delirious.cpp"]
ret = extension(inputs)
k = [".cpp", ".html"]
assert ret == k
kk = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with splitting the filenames using the dot ('.') character to extract the extensions. However, you must first collect all extensions and then count them. Also, using a dictionary to record the counts for each extension helps you to quickly locate the most prevalent ones.

Here is an updated version of your function:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common_extensions(file_list):
    extension_counts = {}

    # Iterate through the list of filenames
    for filename in file_list:
        parts = filename.split(".")
        if len(parts) > 1:  # Check if there's an extension
            extension = "." + parts[-1]  # Get the last part as the extension
            # Increment the count for this extension in the dictionary
            extension_counts[extension] = extension_counts.get(extension, 0) + 1

    # Use Counter to find the most common extensions
    common_extensions = Counter(extension_counts).most_common()

    # Extract just the extensions from the result
    result = [ext for ext, count in common_extensions]

    return result

# Test the function with your example
file_list = ["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar",
          "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3",
          "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "icky.wav",
          "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe",
          "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "annoyed.xml",
          "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "complex.exe",
          "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html",
          "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "hanging.css",
          "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "fortunate.wp",
          "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", "exclusive.als",
          "glossy.css", "fluffy.pt", "cluttered.txt", "halting.cpp", "glib.cpp", "aback.pr",
          "cynical.Ue4", "chilly.xml", "hideous.ala", "finicky.txt", "feigned.ala", "better.Ue4",
          "dear.py", "available.xml", "easy.pr", "fine.mp3", "cowardly.jar", "incredible.css",
          "adhesive.exe", "energetic.mp3", "harmonious.exe", "general.als", "condemned.als",
          "flawless.als", "curvy.h", "ambitious.mp3", "disillusioned.xml", "bitter.h",
          "hanging.wp", "certain.cpp", "flashy.html", "cuddly.pr", "cagey.Ue4", "extra-small.pr",
          "amuck.cpp", "direful.html", "delightful.als", "helpless.h", "foamy.mp3", "enthusiastic.maya",
          "good.maya", "adhesive.css", "imperfect.pr", "bent.cpp", "exultant.zbrush", "adorable.mp3",
          "clammy.maya", "gaudy.pt", "blushing.css", "cuddly.Ue4", "curved.py", "boring.html", "broken.txt",
          "daily.jar", "giddy.xml", "curved.css", "future.maya", "graceful.css", "guiltless.maya",
          "gentle.cpp", "few.css", "calculating.txt", "clear.pr", "grey.py", "entertaining.ala",
          "elfin.txt", "excited.js", "abject.zbrush", "best.js", "boundless.wav", "hurried.ala",
          "delirious.cpp"]
result = most_common_extensions(file_list)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections` Counter to count and `os.path` to split the file names:

```
from collections import Counter
import os

# files list
l = ["direful.pr", "festive.html", "historical.wav", "holistic.mp3", "impossible.jar",
                  "gentle.cpp", "gleaming.xml", "inconclusive.js", "rect.jar", "befitting.mp3",
                  "brief.wp", "beautiful.jar", "energetic.pt", "careful.wp", "defective.cpp", "icky.wav",
                  "gorgeous.txt", "good.pt", "fat.pt", "bored.als", "adaptable.cpp", "fumbling.exe",
                  "grieving.wp", "efficient.wav", "fearful.xml", "damp.html", "erect.exe", "annoyed.xml",
                  "elderly.ala", "far-flung.txt", "careful.mp3", "actually.pt", "cynical.ala", "complex.exe",
                  "extra-small.pt", "enchanted.ala", "amazing.html", "bashful.h", "hallowed.html",
                  "entertaining.html", "bad.js", "illegal.maya", "deadpan.html", "furtive.wp", "hanging.css",
                  "drunk.py", "capricious.wav", "damaging.Ue4", "cool.Ue4", "ambitious.css", "fortunate.wp",
                  "electric.mp3", "crowded.txt", "cooperative.html", "graceful.pt", "aboard.pt", "exclusive.als",
                  "glossy.css", "fluffy.pt", "cluttered.txt", "halting.cpp", "glib.cpp", "aback.pr",
                  "cynical.Ue4", "chilly.xml", "hideous.ala", "finicky.txt", "feigned.ala", "better.Ue4",
                  "dear.py", "available.xml", "easy.pr", "fine.mp3", "cowardly.jar", "incredible.css",
                  "adhesive.exe", "energetic.mp3", "harmonious.exe", "general.als", "condemned.als",
                  "flawless.als", "curvy.h", "ambitious.mp3", "disillusioned.xml", "bitter.h",
                  "hanging.wp", "certain.cpp", "flashy.html", "cuddly.pr", "cagey.Ue4", "extra-small.pr",
                  "amuck.cpp", "direful.html", "delightful.als", "helpless.h", "foamy.mp3", "enthusiastic.maya",
                  "good.maya", "adhesive.css", "imperfect.pr", "bent.cpp", "exultant.zbrush", "adorable.mp3",
                  "clammy.maya", "gaudy.pt", "blushing.css", "cuddly.Ue4", "curved.py", "boring.html", "broken.txt",
                  "daily.jar", "giddy.xml", "curved.css", "future.maya", "graceful.css", "guiltless.maya",
                  "gentle.cpp", "few.css", "calculating.txt", "clear.pr", "grey.py", "entertaining.ala",
                  "elfin.txt", "excited.js", "abject.zbrush", "best.js", "boundless.wav", "hurried.ala",
                  "delirious.cpp"]

extension = []
for elem in l:
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(elem)
    extension.append(file_extension)

c = Counter(extension)

m = Counter(extension).most_common(3)
print('Most common top 3:')
print(m, '\n')

print('Full list of existing extensions, ordered descending')
s = dict(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
for k, v in s.items():
    print(f'{v:<4}x extension: {k}')
```

Output:

```
Most common top 3:
[('.html', 10), ('.cpp', 10), ('.mp3', 9)] 

Full list of existing extensions, ordered descending
10  x extension: .html
10  x extension: .cpp
9   x extension: .mp3
9   x extension: .pt
9   x extension: .css
8   x extension: .txt
7   x extension: .pr
7   x extension: .xml
7   x extension: .ala
6   x extension: .wp
6   x extension: .als
6   x extension: .maya
6   x extension: .Ue4
5   x extension: .wav
5   x extension: .jar
5   x extension: .exe
4   x extension: .js
4   x extension: .h
4   x extension: .py
2   x extension: .zbrush
```